# How to install MS Office 365 ProPlus in Wine?

Tags: wine, 19.10, playonlinux, office365

I have licence for MS Office 365 ProPlus,and I would like to run it on Linux through Wine. So I have 2 questions.
1.)
Why I am getting POL error every time when I try to install 64-bit app through Wine(and Play on Linux)? I tried with both Sytem version and 64-bit version installed throug POL.
2.)
Which wine tricks and ext. libs I need to run it properly. On Wine site I sea that 32-bit version is silver and 64-bit garbage rank. So is there any way or "trick" to get running 64-bit bersion or I need to use 32-bit?

Thank you in advance.